# google data studio, parse date not working on %Y%W format

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, looker-studio

Everything is in the screenshot:
I have a column with date string in format `%Y%W`.
The `PARSE_DATE` function cannot parse the data correctly, it just return the year correctly but doesn't parse the week number

Data sample:

```
week_year
202204
202208
202203
202205
202202
202207
202206
```

[image]

Comment: `%W` is not supported in Google Data Studio's `PARSE_DATE` unfortunately, [as per their docs](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9739156?hl=en). If you have data source that supports SQL, you can try using a custom query to parse the date before it reaches Data Studio.

Answer (score 0):

As @MarcinJ replied

> %W is not supported in Google Data Studio's PARSE_DATE unfortunately, as per their docs. If you have data source that supports SQL, you can try using a custom query to parse the date before it reaches Data Studio

So basically it wont work